# How to group by CLOB data type?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by

Vendor upgrade changed  **column_a** from **VARCHAR2** to **CLOB**. Query that contains a **group by column_a** now returns `ORA-00932 "inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB`.

When I exclude the **group by column_a** in my query, I don't get the error but I don't get the results I want. Thus, I need the group by clause.

Is there a way to group by a CLOB data type?

Comment: Would grouping by the first 4000 bytes of the `clob` be sufficient?  How about grouping by a hash of the `clob`?

Comment: Yes, I think the 1st 4K bytes would be sufficient. To group by 1st 4K would I just select substr(column_a,1,4000) and then group by same way? I'm not familar with grouping by a hash of the `clob`. How does that work?

Comment: Use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (column_a,4000,1)